# Android Textview marquee not working.

Tags: android, marquee

How come the following code not working.  I have something similar at other part of the layout and it works.  But this part does not work.  Any idea?

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"                   
                android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
                android:paddingLeft="50dip" 
                android:paddingRight="50dip"
                android:focusable="true"  
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
                android:id="@+id/statusTvBottom"
                android:text="Status: "                            
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
            </TextView> 
         </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If this is the complete xml file, Add this in your Linear Layout tag xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" or post the complete xml file

Comment: define `not working`.

Comment: @prem, this is part of the xml. I got xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; at the beginning of my xml layout file.  As mentioned, some other TextView using almost the same code works.

Comment: @njzk2, this part of the code supposed to show a text with marquee effect:  the text will move from right to left.  However, only the text is shown, the marquee effect is not there at all.

Comment: marquee effect will be visible only when the textview is selected or in focus. Did you try that ?

Comment: I have tried setting it selected and making it in focus, but still not work: statusTextView.setSelected(true);  statusTextView.requestFocus();

Answer (score 2):

First, the text has to be longer than the "box" in order to marquee, if it fits-no marquee.  I use this code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/availability"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
```

Setting `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` allows it to marquee without focus.

Comment: I think you are right, the text must be longer than the container box for it to marquee.  Does your code work without this restriction?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking here, but the text must be longer than the viewable area to marquee.  If it is all visible then there is no purpose of marquee.  I use this code for a `ListView` and multiple items marquee concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try this:

```
textview.setSelected(true);
```

But it might not work when the text view can't get the focus all the time. So, to ensure TextView Marquee working, I had to use a custom TextView.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if(focused)
            super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
        if(focused)
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then, you can use the custom TextView as the scrolling text view in your layout .xml file like this:

```
<com.example.myapplication.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScrollingMessage"
            android:text="@string/scrolling_message_main_wish_list"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:freezesText="true"/>
```

NOTE: in the above code snippet com.example.myapplication is an example package name and should be replaced by your own package name.

Hope this will help you. Cheers!